# Q: How to specify conditions to be met for this schema?

Tags: json, schema

I'm having this simple schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "A": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "B": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "C": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I would like to enforce these conditions on that schema:

- None of the properties A, B or C is mandatory
- If A is specified, then at least B or C must be specified
- If B or C is specified, there must be A specified.
- B and C must not be specified together

How can I achieve this? I tried a lot with dependencies and allOf/oneOf/anyOf to no avail so far.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like so:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      
      "properties": {
        "A": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "B": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "A",
        "B"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "A": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "C": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "A",
        "C"
      ]
    },
    {
    }
  ]
}
```